# Refresh ComboBox from DataSource and keep selected item, but don't trigger SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Is it a way to refresh the items of a combo box and still keep the selected item so the `SelectedIndexChanged` event will not be triggered? Even if the selected item is not in the new item list?

The following code seems will reset the selected item and trigger `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

```
void RefreshComboboxItems()
{
    var ds = GetRefreshedItems();
    cb.DataSource = ds;
    cb.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cb.ValueMember = "Value";
}

// cb is already initialized and an item is selected
RefreshComboboxItems(); // Want to keep the selected item unchanged and don't trigger the event
```

Comment: @JohnOdom It's supplied in the question code.

Comment: I would be tempted to merely suppress the SelectedIndexChanged event during the operation - by using a boolean guard variable (e.g. "refreshingData") and a try/catch. (The event is guaranteed to be fired inline with the execution of the above code.)

Comment: I can't think of any. Only thing that comes to me is temporarily unassign the handler while you do the dirty work, then pop it back on

Comment: I would hold onto data I knew was selected so I could reselect it after the items changed. Can you guarantee that the selected item will still be in the list or at the same index after refreshing?

Answer (score 2):

No, you could get the current SelectedValue, remove the Event Handler, refresh the combo, try to set again the SelectedValue with the saved value and then readd the Event Handler

```
void RefreshComboboxItems()
{
    try
    {
        int currentValue = -1;
        if(cb.SelectedValue != null) 
          currentValue = Convert.ToInt32(cb.SelectedValue);

       cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= mySelectedIndexChangedMethod;
       var ds = GetRefreshedItems();
       cb.DataSource = ds;
       cb.DisplayMember = "Name";
       cb.ValueMember = "Value";

       if(currentValue != -1)
         cb.SelectedValue = currentValue;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        cb.SelectedIndexChanged += mySelectedIndexChangedMethod;
    }
}
```

Note that I have readded the event handler inside a finally to be sure that the event handler is readded to your combobox also in case an exception causes a premature exit from this code after removing the event handler

Comment: Is it possible to reassign the selected value back even it's not in the new item list?

Comment: If you try to set the SelectedValue to a value that is not in the list there is no effect on the list and you will not have any item selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the event handler temporarily you could do:

```
void RefreshComboboxItems()
{
    cb.SelectedIndexChanged -= Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged;

    var ds = GetRefreshedItems();
    cb.DataSource = ds;
    cb.DisplayMember = "Name";
    cb.ValueMember = "Value";

    cb.SelectedIndexChanged += Ddl_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```